# Load selected date to kendo calendar

Tags: calendar, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm working with Kendo and I've a two controls like dropdown and a calendar. My dropdown contains all dates (01/10/2012, 01/02/2013, 01/01/2014 etc)

And I've a function call on change event of my dropdown. Here i wanted to refresh my calendar based on selected date of my dropdown. I can able to goto the selected date of my calendar. But what happening is everytime a new calendar is getting added to page instead of refreshing the existing one. Can someone help me how to solve this?

Here is my trail

```
$("#holidays").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            change: function () {
   var calendar = $("#holidaysCalendar").kendoCalendar().data("kendoCalendar");
                     calendar.value(new Date($("#holidays").val));
}
```

Comment: I've changed the above code slightly and it is working now. var calendar = $("#holidaysCalendar").data("kendoCalendar");
                     calendar.value(new Date($("#holidays").val));

Answer (score 0):

Just so you don't get confused,

with this code you create a new kendoCalendar

```
var calendar = $("#holidaysCalendar").kendoCalendar();  // use it once on create
```

with this, you get the data of an existing kendoCalendar

```
var calendar = $("#holidaysCalendar").data("kendoCalendar"); // use it to get the data
```

So use the first code to create your calendar once, and you can access it's data every time with the second line of code.

Comment: Hey Antonis.. thanks for your reply.. Yes I did in the same way and it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var calendar = $("#holidaysCalendar").data("kendoCalendar").value().toString();
```

Comment: also add description of your answer.

Comment: it's just a line to add in javascript code to get the string value of the selected date of the calendar